# How to train TensorFlow on multiple devices which don't have GPUs?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed-computing, distributed

Suppose we have a simple TensorFlow model with a few convolutional layers. We like to train this model on a cluster of computers that is not equipped with GPUs. Each computational node of this cluster might have 1 or multiple cores. Is it possible out-of-the-box?
If not, which packages are able to do that? Are those packages able to perform data and model parallelism?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training)

> tf.distribute.Strategy is a TensorFlow API to distribute training across multiple GPUs, multiple machines or TPUs.

As mentioned above it supports CPU for distributed training by considering all  devices should be in the same network.

Yes, you can use multiple devices for training model and need to have cluster and worker configuration to be done on couple of devices as shown below.

```
tf_config = {
    'cluster': {
        'worker': ['localhost:1234', 'localhost:6789']
    },
    'task': {'type': 'worker', 'index': 0}
}
```

To know about the configuration and training model, please refer [Multi-worker training with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras).

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64211440/14290681)

> `tf.distribute.Strategy` is integrated to `tf.keras`, so when `model.fit` is
> used with `tf.distribute.Strategy` instance and then using
> `strategy.scope()` for your model allows to create distributed
> variables. This allows it to equally divide your input data on your
> devices.

Note: One can be benefited using distributed training when dealing with huge data and complex models (i.e. w.r.t performance).